# Why i m getting "Not secure" in front of website name in the url?

Tags: java, php, asp.net

I have issue with website url.When I enter website url in the chrome,then websites name comes with

> Not secure| www.mywebsitesname.com

How can I change this to

> Secure |http://mywebsitesname.com

Is it possible?

Comment: get ssl certificate to make your site secure

Comment: Because you are having http in your url. To remove that get https. You can get https you should get ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible make your website secure. You need to buy a `SSL` certificate for that and set all internal url to run on `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP`. Because `HTTP` is not secure.

You can buy SSL certificate from [Godaddy](https://in.godaddy.com/offers/default.aspx?isc=sshl5in31&tmskey=1ssl_3&pcode=310211712&compchart=1&currencytype=INR&cvosrc=ppc.google.godaddy%20ssl&cvo_crid=167354786584&matchtype=e&mkwid=ssT6pDr2E_pcrid_167354786584_pkw_godaddy%20ssl_pmt_e_pdv_c&gclid=CjwKEAiA8dDEBRDf19yI97eO0UsSJAAY_yCSbny81B7m8n7fQbJDuItXDLGpryumMgYidMk-p7FCKhoCsD7w_wcB)

After that your site will have something like this before url

[image]

For more on `HTTP VS HTTPS` please read [this](https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/https.html)

Answer (score 0):

### Change your url HTTP to HTTPS by SSL certification

**HTTP VS HTTPS**

Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Secure (HTTPS) is the secure version of HTTP, the protocol over which data is sent between your browser and the website that you are connected to. The 'S' at the end of HTTPS stands for 'Secure'. It means all communications between your browser and the website are encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

From begin of 2017 more (especially e-commerce) site that don't have the 
*https*
are signed with 'non sicure'. To solve this problem you can implements on your site the https module simpy to buy a SSL from your provider.